# Opening remote file using PHP

Tags: php, remote-file-inclusion

I have a PHP page where i want to open a file on a remote machine and read its contents. I  have to specify the remote machine's IP address. How can this be done in PHP ?

Comment: file_get_contents() is often disabled because of security resctrictions. If so, take a look ac cURL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo file_get_contents("http://1.1.1.1/file.txt")`

Answer (score 1):

You can read the contents of any file with `file_get_contents()`.

Docs: http://php.net/file_get_contents

Comment: One more thing...when i open file using fopen(), i can detect its end using feof(). But how do i do that with a string ?

Comment: you don't need it on a string.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the ip of the remote machine. You can just use

```
file_get_contents('http path to file');
```