# How to open URL with php loop and send callback when each one finish?

Tags: php

I want to open URL with parameter from 1 to 100, for example. And send callback to the original script that the destination is finish in loop.

Is there any way to do this with PHP alone?

For example,

```
for($i=0;$i<$urls;$i++){
  header("location:https://www.hellokitty.com/userupdate.php?id=$i");
  $_SESSION['progress']=$i;
}
```

So, I can update the progress with ajax display the process update.

Comment: `file_get_contents` or `curl`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening remote file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221980/opening-remote-file-using-php)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish and why?  This code doesn't "open a URL", it *directs the user* to the URL.  If a single response contains multiple such location headers, the user's browser isn't going to perform multiple sequential redirects for you.  Are you instead trying to send an HTTP request to this URL from server-side code?

Comment: I'm trying to update the destination url to DB without coding a whole bunch of script. Once I submit a url the script runs and write data to DB. I have 100 user ids so it's easier to call the url with each id in loop.

Comment: Did either of previous mentioned solutions work?

Comment: @user3783243 Not yet, I still cannot run the url to process the script with file_get_contents

Comment: What happens when you try that? Please add details to the question.